# jQuery anchor tag to add a class to a div with the same parent as the anchor tag's parent

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to get this anchor tag to add a class to a div with the same parent as it's parent.
I've research jQuery documentation and tried several approaches to the selectors but nothing seems to work.

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <div><a href="#" class="pop">produto 1</a><div>
    <div class="product_frame"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div><a href="#" class="pop">produto 2</a><div>
    <div class="product_frame"></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I'm almost sure that the problem is with my jQuery function, particularly on the selector but I've been stuck on this for quite some time so right now I'm thinking that it might be something else, like maybe the particular selection I'm aiming for is not feasible with the selectors parent/child.

This is my jQuery function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("a .pop").click(function() {
       $(this).parents().find('product_frame').addClass("active");
});
```

I think this is the only relevant code. Can any one tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Edit:
I tried implementing the following:

```
$("a.pop").click(function() {
   $(this).parent().next('.product_frame').addClass("active");
});

 $("a.popup").click(function() {

      $(this).closest("li").find('.product_frame').addClass("active");
 });
```

But the class is still not being added when the anchor tag is clicked. Maybe it's a problem with the function declaration?

My CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">

.product_frame {
    position:fixed;
    top:120px;
    left:180px;
    right:80px;
    bottom:120px;
    display:none;
}

a.pop {
    text-decoration:none;
}

.active {
    display:block;
}

</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is wroking jquery

```
$("a.popup").click(function() {
   $(this).parent().find('.product_frame').addClass("active");
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Amit12x/HreV3/1)

Comment: I think not. I tried to implement the answers give thus far but the active class is still not being added. But i don't know what is wrong with the code.

Comment: it's working fine. check out fiddle.after clicking on list item, check out by inspecting element. it is adding class "Active" to that div. 
check it

Comment: BTW what what action do you to perform after adding active class. if you have css for your active class then give your css code. it will help me to solve your problem.

Comment: I edited on the original question, added the relevant CSS. Thank you for trying to help.

Comment: my code is working fine . check my updated fiddle, where i edited your css by adding color property (just for ensuring active class added or not )for active class.
http://jsfiddle.net/Amit12x/HreV3/1/

Comment: It's working on jsfiddle but it's still not working on my page. the anchor is still not adding the class.

Comment: wait do you also want to active class to anchor tag too, or only in div . if yes then just write this code

$("a.popup").click(function() {
   $(this).parent().find('.product_frame').addClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});

Comment: I just figured it out.Was the most basic mistake ever. wrong place for the script to go to. I just moved it to the end of the body and now it's working. Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 2):

First remove the space between the anchor and the class. That would look for an elements that's a descendant of the anchor. Second, use `.parent()` and `.next()` (with the period to designate the class):

```
$("a.pop").click(function() {
   $(this).parent().next('.product_frame').addClass("active");
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/SY3jX/4/)**

(Note: be sure to close your divs properly. In your example they are closed with opening div tags)

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious mistake I'm seeing here is your selector:

```
$("a .pop")
```

It finds elements with class "pop" *within* an anchor element. What you want is:

```
$('a.pop')
```

I.e. find elements with tag name "a" *and* the class "pop".

The other issue is that `.parents()` will give you the parents all the way up to the start of your document, so `<div>`, `<li>`, `<ul>`, ..., `<body>`, etc.

Instead you need only go back to the nearest `<li>` ancestor and then perform another search; also "product_frame" is not an element name, to match a class you need a leading period:

```
$('a.pop').closest('li').children('.product_frame')
```

Alternatively, you can do what j08691 proposed and select the parent first (div) and then select its next sibling element.